# Malaria Mortality Rate GIS Data

Tags: data, geography, health

Can anyone direct me to GIS data for malaria mortality rate?

I am looking for countries in South Asia, but not looking for country level numbers but smaller level numbers like district level.

Comment: The usual advice is to try the opendata version (https://opendata.stackexchange.com/). What have you already looked at? WHO? Any country-specific sites? If you tell us what you've already done, its easier to avoid telling you something you already know.

Answer (score 1):

Humanitarian Data Exchange is a data portal for humanitarian purpose.
[Have a look](https://data.humdata.org)

To get Malaria datasets you can search with their seach box or go throught this [URL](https://data.humdata.org/search?q=Malaria)

As you Can see their are lot of CSV files Like [there](https://data.humdata.org/dataset/total_number_of_reported_malaria_cases/resource/34d37a3c-2c0b-4ec2-9d3c-eec9b11ca72f?view_id=3ff46c04-7471-450f-809f-6018677822fe) where data are report by country and for several years